# Spring boot @Retryable Mock test fails

Tags: java, spring-boot

Test case fails to retry multiple times (2), it tries once and the exception is thrown

my application class has **EnableRetry** annotation

```js
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.***")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableRetry
public class Application {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

This is the service class that has the method I want to retry.

```js
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@EnableRetry //just in case, this didn't help though!!
public class DataSetService {
  
  //some objects
  private int count;
  .....
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 86400000)
  @Retryable(value = {OptimisticLockException.class}, maxAttemptsExpression = 2, backoff = 
    @Backoff(delayExpression = 1000))
  public void updateDataSetExp() {
        LOG.info("Count : " + count++); //Expecting this count to be 3 after re-tries
        Date dateBeforeExpiry = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - THIRTY_DAYS_IN_MS);
        List<DataSet> expiredDataSets = 
                               dataSetRepository.findByCreatedAtBefore(dateBeforeExpiry);
        for (DataSet expiredDs : expiredDataSets) {
          expiredDs.setExpired(true);
          dataSetRepository.save(expiredDs);
        }
    }
}
@Recover
public void updateDataSetExpFallback(OptimisticLockException e) {
    LOG.error("Optimistic locking issues found");
}
```

My test case

```js
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DataSetServiceRunnerTest {
    @Autowired
    private DataSetService dataSetService;
    DataSetCreateRequest dataSetCreateRequest;
    DataSet dataSet;
    @MockBean
    DataSetRepository dataSetRepository;
    //all other mock beans that are required

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        dataSetService = new DataSetService(dataReferenceRepository, dataSetRepository, 
        principalService,userInfoService, ccStorageService, elasticConfiguration, 
        clusterRepository, encryptionService, awsService);
                
        dataSet = new DataSet();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateDataSetExpiryOptimisticLock(){

        List<DataSet> expiredDataSetList = new ArrayList<>();
        expiredDataSetList.add(dataSet);
        when(dataSetRepository.findByCreatedAtBefore(any(Date.class)))
        .thenReturn(expiredDataSetList);
        
        when(dataSetRepository.save(any(DataSet.class)))
        .thenThrow(OptimisticLockException.class);

        try {
            dataSetService.updateDataSetExp();
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }

        verify(dataSetRepository, times(3)).save(dataSet);
        verify(dataSetRepository, times(3)).findByCreatedAtBefore(any(Date.class));
    }

}
```

I am expecting **dataSetRepository.findByCreatedAtBefore** method to be invoked 3 times and then the exception is thrown but in my case, it is only invoked once. also, the **count** is expected to be 3 but is 1.

I've tried looking into other posts and followed the documentation around Retryable but didn't help. Can someone provide some pointers.

Comment: Can you try calling the `updateDataSetExp()` from some other class? I mean instead of putting the `@Scheduled(..)` on the top of this method in this class, create a different class and create a method annotated with `@Scheduled` and make a call to this method from another class.

Comment: In fact, I tried the above test case without having `@Scheduled` annotation and the result was the same. My understanding is that though I use `SpringBootTest` on my test class, DataSetService is manually initialized in the setup method. This might be causing Spring to not do all the magic behind and `Retryable` is not honored. That's my reasoning for now.

Answer (score 0):

In your test case `setup()` is not required ideally because `@SpringBootTest` will load Spring context and all Beans will be initialized explicitly.

Also, I tried to replicate your setup and it seems to be working fine with and without `@Scheduled`

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RetryDirectService {

    private final TestService testService;

    @Retryable(value = NumberFormatException.class, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(500))
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public String getData() {
        return testService.getData();
    }

    @Recover
    public String recoverData(String appender) {
        log.info("Calling recoverData");
        return "DEFAULT";
    }

}
    

@SpringBootTest
public class RetryDirectServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RetryDirectService retryDirectService;

    @MockBean
    private TestService testService;

    @Test
    public void testShouldRetryTillMaxAttemptsAndCallsRecoveryBlock(){
        //Given
        Mockito.when(testService.getData()).thenThrow(new NumberFormatException());
        //When
        retryDirectService.getData();
        //Then
        verify(testService, Mockito.times(4)).getData();
    }
}
```

The only deviation was that with `@Scheduled`,  `getData()` was called 5 times. Which is expected. 4 times for retry and one time when triggered by the scheduler.

For more detail in Retry setup plase refer [this](https://ashishontech.xyz/spring-retry-in-action/) post